# how to solve generator-angular error

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

When i tried to install generator-angular in yeoman using following command i get several error and i have no clue how to solve them.

```
npm install -g generator-angular
```

```
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency generator-karma@>=0.9.0 included from generator-angular will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN deprecated CSSselect@0.4.1: the module is now available as 'css-select'
npm WARN deprecated CSSwhat@0.4.7: the module is now available as 'css-what'
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency yo@>=1.0.0 included from generator-karma will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Ranjeet\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\readable-stream\2.0.2\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Ranjeet\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\readable-stream\2.0.2\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Ranjeet\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\lodash\3.10.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Ranjeet\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\readable-stream\2.0.2\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Ranjeet\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\readable-stream\2.0.2\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Ranjeet\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\readable-stream\2.0.2\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Ranjeet\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\readable-stream\1.0.33\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Ranjeet\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\is-utf8\0.2.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Ranjeet\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\first-chunk-stream\1.0.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Ranjeet\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\is-utf8\0.2.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Ranjeet\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\first-chunk-stream\1.0.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Ranjeet\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\rx\2.5.3\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Ranjeet\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\readable-stream\1.1.13\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Ranjeet\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\replace-ext\0.0.1\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Ranjeet\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\clone\1.0.2\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Ranjeet\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\clone-stats\0.0.1\package.tgz
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "generator-angular"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Ranjeet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-karma\node_modules\yeoman-generator\node_modules\lodash\lang\isObject.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT, open 'C:\Users\Ranjeet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-karma\node_modules\yeoman-generator\node_modules\lodash\lang\isObject.js'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother about the warnings on `peerDependencies` (this is the way yeoman generators are coded, it will change for npm's next version)

About your errors, I see they are all about unpacking files from the cache (those files might have been corrupt while downloading). Try `npm cache clean` then re-install.

Comment: Thanks for your help